# Attempt to index "group" (A nill value)

Tags: lua

Im new to Lua and can only just really read it, mainly just interpreting. I was having an error with a modification for Garrys mod where a lightsaber mod I had installed worked on client side but was invisible on server side. This is because of settings, ect. I asked on his group and he told me this :

You must call these functions on the weapon right after spawning it:

```
self:SetMaxLength( 42 )
self:SetCrystalColor( Vector( 255, 0, 0 ) )
self:SetDarkInner( false )
self:SetWorldModel( "models/... etc" )
self:SetBladeWidth( 2 )
self.LoopSound = "sound/lightsaber/..."
self.SwingSound = "sound/lightsaber/..."
self:SetOnSound( "sound/lightsaber/..." )
self:SetOffSound( "sound/lightsaber/..." )
self.WeaponSynched = true
```

Where self is the weapon.

So I put it into the code. All this does is completely remove the lightsaber and give me this error:

```
[ERROR] lua/weapons/weapon_lightsaber.lua:44: attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value)
  1. unknown - lua/weapons/weapon_lightsaber.lua:44
```

Here is the pastebin of the code : http://pastebin.com/Y8kmivuv

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'SWEP' instead of 'self'. self is usually defined in object-orientated code, which uses metatables in Lua.